# Getting domains names and SPF and Mx record from an IP powershell

Tags: email, powershell, spf

so i was wondering if i can get from an IP adresse the domain name and it's SPF and MX record (if exists) using PowerShell
i've found some interesting scripts on the internet for getting domain names and SPF and MX

but the problem i have is :
- there Are some domains that share the same IP called "shared hosting" and in my scripts i used these codes

```
[System.Net.Dns]::gethostentry($ip)
```

and

```
[system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip)
```

the two of these scripts doesn't get me all the domain names for an Ip, I don't know what to change

And My second question is about MX records, for the moment i'm only getting infos about it, i'm planing to make records for my domains but i want to know if there's any relation between mx records and how much can a domain send of mails a day

I read some info's about high mx record and low and some nubers you put in the config but i don't really understand well.

Thank You and i hope this question isn't duplicated cuz i searched a lot in the site and didn't found what i want.

Comment: Please realize that just because a domain name points to an IP address in DNS, doesn't mean that the IP address also points to the domain name in DNS.

Comment: But i've found some web sites that allow you to get all the domains pointing on a given IP, how do they do that ? there must be a way

Comment: Sure, it will work if multiple PTR records for the IP in question exists, but it's not guaranteed to work (in most cases it won't). Give an example of such an IP and I'll try to explain

Comment: Umm ... i think i don't get the PTR record meaning can you explain it too ? please
and about the exemple here's a service that allow getting all domain names pointing on a given IP http://reverseip.domaintools.com/search/?q=209.133.200.73

Comment: PTR is a DNS (reverse lookup) record type that maps IP addresses to domain names. The reverseip tool on domaintools.com on the other hand uses pre-learned knowledge about which domain names points to which IP addresses to figure it out the other way around. They can only do that because they already have a huge database of domains that people have queried

Comment: I get it now, That's why it's a paid service, so it's not always possible to get domain names using only an IP, thank u i had a big confusion.
and about the MX record does it have any relation with how much a domain can send of emails or like DKIM it's just an identifier for the domain sender ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95693/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-mohamed-abarri).